# WPF show a control to end of a Dynamic textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF I want to show a control in a way that it should follow the contents of a dynamic Binding textblock. The xaml structre I used is:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
<DockPanel  Margin="2,3">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right"> //right side control here
        <Button Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=dbokLinkStyle}" Content="delete">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>     
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Quote}"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
        <Button Tag="{Binding}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Page"/>
            </StackPanel>     
        </Button>
    </WrapPanel>                                                        
</DockPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    Row 2 controls..
</StackPanel>
```

I want to show Page Button immediatly after the Textblock with binding Quotes. But the above xaml makes it always on right corner only. So how can I make it to follow the textblock control.
The layout is more like 
[image]

Comment: Instead of a wrappanel can you not have a horizontal stackpanel?

Comment: Then i cant see the textblock full content , Max width of window is 800 and if textblock content exceeds that ?

Comment: Sorry I think i understood wrong, is it the delete button you want right next to the header page information?

Comment: NO i can manage to show the delete button on right always using dockpanel ,But i am not been able to make the control showing date text in a way that it follow the header. If i use stackpanel the length of header is too much i cant see the controls also [since horizontal scrolling is disabled]

Comment: If the header is too long can you not truncate it and then show the full header in tooltip? or do you want to show the header in too lines if it doesnt fit in one line?

Comment: I want to show complete header + butt\on control with date time following it

Comment: @Krishna I think you have misinterpreted what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your WrapPanel with something like this:-

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
  <TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Foo}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <Button Content="Page" />
</TextBlock>
```

The entire TextBlock will wrap as its contents (i.e. the inner TextBlock *and* Button) get too long.

Comment: Yes this is somewhat similar to what i am looking for .Is there any specific rules in this layout so the Button Page appear on next to TextBlock . Reason is sometimes even with enough space on right the Button appears on Second Line , but sometimes on next to TextBlock itself

Comment: @JMat not sure. Perhaps being affected by a margin around something? You'll probablyt want to remove the TextTrimming property as this is irrelevant now, as it will never be trimmed.